# Why does this template syntax produce different results in Clang/GCC/MSVC

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, syntax, clang

**Background info**

I am in the process of writing a simple container over function pointers to make calling pointers from other modules in memory easier (for things like video game modding, api hooking, etc.)

Currently, I am using a partial specialization to pattern match user provided tags (empty structures) to help the compiler to know what the potential calling convention of the function is. (stdcall, cdecl, etc.)

The templates look *similar* in implementation to these two minimal reproductions.

```cpp
#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__)
#define CC_CDECL __attribute__((cdecl))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#define CC_CDECL __cdecl
#endif

template<typename RT, typename ...A>
struct T1 { using type = RT (CC_CDECL) (A...); };

template<typename RT, typename ...A>
struct T2 { using type = RT CC_CDECL (A...); };

template<typename RT, typename ...A>
struct T3 { using type = CC_CDECL RT (A...); };
```

which are used similarly to this
**Test cases**

```cpp
void example_function() {}
int main()
{
    T1<void>::type* test;
    T2<void>::type* test2;
    T3<void>::type* test3;
    auto test4 = example_function;
    std::cout << typeid(test).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(test2).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(test3).name() << "\n";
    std::cout << typeid(test4).name() << "\n";
}
```

When using `T1` MSVC and GCC both produce typeids of `PFvvE` and `void (__cdecl*)(void)` respectively for both the `::type*` and for the raw pointer to the function. **It fails to compile on Clang**.

When using `T2` MSVC, GCC, and Clang **all compile**, however GCC produces the **typeid** for `::type*` with a typeid of `PU5cdeclFvvE` instead of `PFvvE`. Clang and MSVC both produce typeids of `PFvvE` and `void (__cdecl*)(void)` respectively for both the `::type*` and for the raw pointer to the function.  This means either GCC has the wrong typeid or MSVC and Clang both have the wrong typeid for this test case.

The same strange behavior in GCC that happened in `T2` happens when using `T3`; However, **MSVC will now fail to compile.** Clang produces expected results in this test case.

**Question**

*Why* do these various syntactical changes affect each compiler so differently, and so drastically?

Additionally, are these compiler rejections defects in the compiler? Why does GCC accept all of them but throw out different typeids for syntax that produces congruent typeids on other compilers?

**Reproduction Steps/Godbolt**
All four test cases, comment out each one as needed for the respective compiler that rejects a particular test case noted above.
https://godbolt.org/z/jear9c675

**Edit**

Test case 2 seems to produce congruent types, even when GCC shows `PU5cdeclFvvE`instead of `PFvvE` (tested with std::is_same and by retrieving the target of std::function.)

What this tells me is that these are probably small AST/Code generation bugs and I'll probably have to reach out to all three organizations to see what should be legal and what the final expected behavior is.

**Addendum (In case anyone is asking about *why* this syntax)**

I understand that using `T (calling convention*) (A...)` is the syntax for the type of a function pointer; In this context the point of using `T (calling convention) (A...)` is it will be utilized as such

```cpp
    using X = T(calling convention)(A...);
    X* ptr;
```

similar to

```cpp
    using X = void; 
    X* ptr;
```

As-is, I can work-around this issue between the compilers with macros; I don't need any solutions to the "problem" itself.

Comment: Instead of `using X = T()(A...);` you can just write `using X = T(A...);` Actually I can't get the longer version to compile.

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for the input.

Unfortunately, `using X = T(A...);` doesn't provide the calling convention to the underlying pointer type, which is sadly a requirement to make this work with x86 code (various things use stdcall, cdecl, etc.)

The addendum has a simplified version, but there _should_ normally be a calling convention specified in the first set of `()`.

I'll edit that area for clarity!

Comment: Things like __cdecl and __stdcall are compiler extensions to indicate calling conventions.  Deal with compiler extensions using conditional compiling as different compilers being extended in precisely same way is rare coincidence, not rule.

Comment: I agree, normally this is the case, however the specific extensions are macro'ed out to each compiler, and this also fails to explain why the typeid varies in GCC for the different signatures that should all (at least most should) collapse back into a pointer to a function.

The other question that would need to be addressed is what is (if any) the formal standard for function types with attributes?

In all three the convention attributes prefix the function declaration; I find it strange that they would have such discontinuity for pointers to those functions. (Totally possible though!)

Comment: The C standard says nothing about this. Typeid varies in GCC because that's what GCC decided to do.

Comment: Which still leads to the question as to _why_ GCC decided to do what it did, the designers had to have had _some_ reason to handle those differently internally (and differently compared to other compilers.)

Comment: I cannot answer why GCC developers decided to do this. If you think they should not have, open a bug. Perhaps it is a bug. The types are actually the same (check with `std::is_same`) although the typeids are different.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t even think to check with std::is_same. Depending on the implications the difference may not matter in the end and could simply be a curiosity.